# Interactive Grid

Tags: matlab, grid, interactive

I am trying to create a grid in MATLAB.

The number of rows and columns for the grid are to be entered by the user during run-time.

When the user clicks on a particular block/square of the grid,

1. I need to obtain the co-ordinates of the block (i.e. `(1,1)`, `(2,3)` etc.)
2. I also need to color that square/block.

Any suggestions as to how I can do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may serve as a starter:

```
% draw a rectangle
% store coordinates in the userdata
r = rectangle('Position', [1 1 1 1], 'UserData', [1,1], 'FaceColor', 'r');
% set the clicked-callback:
set(r, 'ButtonDownFcn', @showIndex);

function showIndex(hObject, evt)
    disp('Clicked on:');
    disp(get(hObject, 'UserData'));
end
```

[Code syntax edited]

**EDIT:**

Concerning the coordinates:
You can of course use your own coordinates, presumably you get a loop similar to this:

```
for ix=1:n % loop over columns
    for iy=1:m % loop over rows
        % modify coordinates to your needs
        % e.g. to make the y-index start at 1 from top to bottom:
        coords = [ix,m-iy+1]; 
        r(ix,iy) = rectangle('Position', [ix,iy,1,1], 'UserData', coords, ...);
        % remaining stuff...
    end
end
```

Comment: so do you recommend that I create as many rectangles as input by the user? For example if the user inputs that he wants a 5x5 grid, should I create 25 rectangles?

Comment: I tried creating multiple rectangles but the coordinates `(1,1)` start from bottom left instead of top left. Any suggestions as to how to deal with this situation too.

Comment: See my edit above - you're free to set 'UserData' according to your own coordinate system.

Comment: That worked! How could I draw both diagonals in each square/rectangle and place a text in each of the 4 partitions.

Comment: Check the documentation on `line` and `text`. You'll just have to calculate the coordinates of the 4 edges and the center of the rectangle to draw the lines and a center-aligned text.

Comment: Could you please answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421751/draw-square-with-diagonal-lines-and-display-text-matlab?noredirect=1#comment32323765_21421751